# Can we filter CSV files using CsvJdbc where two columns are equal?

Tags: java, jdbc, csvjdbc

I am trying to use a query that compares two column values, e.g.,

```
Select * from table where header1 = header2
```

but it does not seem to be working for me. Is this supported in CsvJdbc?

Comment: I didn't see  any question mark here.

Comment: I want to use query like this. Is there any way to execute this query using CSV-JDBC api in Java???

Comment: Did you try it? It is a JDBC driver so use like a normal one until it doesn't work, then you found a feature that is not implemented.

Comment: Yes i tried this. But not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work. Confirmed with csvjdbc-1.0-28.jar. With the CSV file

```
id,header1,header2
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,2,1
4,2,2
```

and the Java code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("columnTypes", "INTEGER");
    try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:C:/Users/Gord/Desktop", props);
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM table WHERE header1=header2")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

}
```

the result is

```
1
4
```